# ValueError arisen in unexpected case

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

I have been running a litte python function of my own and got this unexpected ValueError :

**Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series**

The error arised putting a specific value ( 0 ) into one of the three arguments of my function ( the **n_col_num** argument ).

I then put in a comment block the part of the function where the **n_col_num** argument is used and kept receiving the same ValueError.

I have then identified the part of the code raising the alerte, which is :

```
df[ col ] = pd.DataFrame( [ random.choice( rand_val_hat ) for _ in range( n_rows )] )
```

For more details, here is my function code :

```
def rand_df_wrk ( n_col_num , lst_par_col_str , n_rows ) :

    """
     n_col_num : number of numeric columns

     lst_par_col_str : tuple ( a , b ) where a is the number of values in a hat of values and b the number of characters 
                   of each values ( all values are built with the same number of characters )

     n_rows : number of rows in the dataframe
    """

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    if n_col_num > 0 : 
        for i in range( n_col_num ) :
            # name of new numeric column :
            col = 'col_num_' + str( i )
            # values for the new numeric column 
            df[ col ] = np.random.normal( 0 , 1 , n_rows ) 

    if len( lst_par_col_str ) > 0 :  
        for i , par in enumerate( lst_par_col_str ) :
            # name of new string column :
            col = 'col_str_' + str( i )
            # values for sampling with replacement :
            rand_val_hat = rand_str_lst( par[0] , par[1] )
            # values for the new string column :
            df[ col ] = pd.DataFrame( [ random.choice( rand_val_hat ) for _ in range( n_rows )] )

    return df
```

**rand_df_wrk** uses the following function :

```
 def rand_str_lst( N , n ) :

   """
    N : number of string values
    n : number of characters for each string values ( each string value is built with the same number of characters )
   """

   rand_str_lst = []
   for i in range( N ) :
       rand_str_lst.append( rand_str( n ) )
   return rand_str_lst
```

and then **rand_str_lst** function uses this last one :

```
def rand_str ( n ) :

   """
    n : number of random characters in the returned string
   """

   rand_string = ''.join( random.SystemRandom().choices( string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits , k = n ) )
   return rand_string
```

( **I don't think the 2 previous functions are of any importance for my case.** )

When calling for example the **rand_df_wrk** function that way :

```
rand_df_wrk( n_col_num = 2 , lst_par_col_str = [ ( 5 , 3 ) , ( 2 , 1 ) ] , n_rows = 10 )
```

I get the expected result ( a random dataframe built with 2 numeric columns, 2 string columns and 10 rows ).

If I call it that way :

```
rand_df_wrk( n_col_num = 0 , lst_par_col_str = [ ( 5 , 3 ) , ( 2 , 1 ) ] , n_rows = 10 )
```

I get the ErrorValue aforementioned.

It occured because the following block was not executed :

```
if n_col_num > 0 : 
        for i in range( n_col_num ) :
            # name of new numeric column :
            col = 'col_num_' + str( i )
            # values for the new numeric column 
            df[ col ] = np.random.normal( 0 , 1 , n_rows )
```

So it occured in the next block of my main function :

```
if len( lst_par_col_str ) > 0 :  
    for i , par in enumerate( lst_par_col_str ) :
        # name of new string column :
        col = 'col_str_' + str( i )
        # values for sampling with replacement :
        rand_val_hat = rand_str_lst( par[0] , par[1] )
        # values for the new string column :
        df[ col ] = pd.DataFrame( [ random.choice( rand_val_hat ) for _ in range( n_rows )] )
```

And in particular there :

```
df[ col ] = pd.DataFrame( [ random.choice( rand_val_hat ) for _ in range( n_rows )] )
```

but I can't figure out why and then can'f fix it.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: it would be nice if you spot the error yourself, and just attach one line of code, or the minimal example that reproduces the error and nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution : instead of

```
df[ col ] = pd.DataFrame( [ random.choice( rand_val_hat ) for _ in range( n_rows ) ] )
```

I tried :

```
df[ col ] = pd.Series( [ random.choice( rand_val_hat ) for _ in range( n_rows ) ] )
```

( cf. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5632 )